# Why cant truffle be installed

Tags: installation, truffle

**Background information:**

I run macOS 10.14.6. I just started my programming journey so please forgive me if my questions are not rock solid... Grateful for your guidance regarding my problem!

**Problem:**

I failed to install Truffle when executing `npm install -f truffle`. I tried to uninstall and install it but the problem remains. I think my problem has to do with my path variable, but I don't really understand how to practically work on this.

**Terminal error message**

> npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.

> truffle@5.0.33 postinstall /Users/lapqal/node_modules/truffle
> node ./scripts/postinstall.js

```
Fetching solc version list from solc-bin. Attempt #1
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/lapqal/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/lapqal/package.json'
npm WARN lapqal No description
npm WARN lapqal No repository field.
npm WARN lapqal No README data
npm WARN lapqal No license field.

truffle@5.0.33
updated 1 package and audited 336 packages in 7.686s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Thank you for your time

Yoenca

Comment: try this ```npm i truffle```

Comment: Did you initialize a `package.json` file by using `npm init`?

Comment: Thanks for the edit revision and the quick reply! I will look up your tips, and get back here if I need further help.

Comment: Try `npm install -g truffle`